# PHP : complex Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have created an example page .Please see [here](http://livestreamly.com/)

I want to get the event name and timing seperately. Can anyone help me?

For example. From the line

```
***ENGLISH* MLB: Philadelphia Phillies at Miami Marlins 12.00am-3.00am Stream 7**
```

Note: ***ENGLISH* varies all time...time varies to am,pm

I want event name,timing,and stream number like below seperately

```
MLB: Minnesota Twins at Atlanta Braves
12.00am-3.00am
7
```

I've tried

```
$game = file_get_contents("http://livestreamly.com/");
preg_match_all('/<font color="gold">(.*?)<p>/',$game,$match);
```

This gives whole live. Please help me.

Comment: You need to find unique patterns from your input that can be found in all lines, eg the first `:` or the `\d?\d\.\d\d[ap]m-\d?\d\.\d\d[ap]m` to build a reliable regex. Or you could split (`explode`) your lines, and select tokens from resulting array, eg the nth from start, the mth from the end... (since Phil Phillies for instance seems to have random number of words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked with your site and this regex is valid for your problem

```
/<\/font>([a-zA-Z0-9\'.: -]+)([0-9]{1,2}.+?[0-9]{1,2}[a,p,A,P,m,M]{2})-([0-9]{1,2}[.:]+?[0-9]{1,2}[a,p,A,P,m,M]{2}) <font color="red">Stream ([0-9]+)<\/font>/
```

I've checked with http://regexpal.com/ when you use preg_match_all; output array matches will contain information you need. You need to escape some chars in this regex to put it into php variable.

PHP valid code:

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all('/<\/font>([a-zA-Z0-9\'.: -]+)([0-9]{1,2}.+?[0-9]{1,2}[a,p,A,P,m,M]{2})-([0-9]{1,2}[.:]+?[0-9]{1,2}[a,p,A,P,m,M]{2}) <font color="red">Stream ([0-9]+)<\/font>/',file_get_contents("http://livestreamly.com/"),$match);
print_r($match);
```

Some of output:

```
[1] => array(37) {
    [0] => string(45) " MLB: Philadelphia Phillies at Miami Marlins "
    [1] => string(40) " MLB: Minnesota Twins at Atlanta Braves "
    [2] => string(39) " MLB: Cincinnati Reds at New York Mets "
[2] => array(37) {
    [0] => string(14) "12.00am-3.00am"
    [1] => string(14) "12.00am-3.00am"
    [2] => string(14) "12.00am-3.00am"
    [3] => string(14) "12:00am-3:00am"
    [4] => string(14) "12.15am-2.15am"
    [5] => string(14) "12.30AM-3.30AM"
[3] => array(37) {
    [0] => string(1) "6"
    [1] => string(1) "7"
    [2] => string(1) "8"
    [3] => string(1) "9"
    [4] => string(2) "10"
```

**How it works**

Firstly it looks for  then for subpattern `[a-zA-Z0-9'.: -]+` which means characters from a-z and A-Z, digits from 0-9 ' . : or - which must occur at least once or more. It matches name.

```
 ([0-9]{1,2}.+?[0-9]{1,2})
```

Later it looks for first part of hour which is numerical and has 1 or 2 digits, then i can be any character at least once with greedy operator. Then other number(minutes) at least 1 or 2 digits.

```
 [a,p,A,P,m,M]{2}
```

Is responsible for AM or am or pm or PM it can be also AA or MM but it doesn't matter here.

```
<font color="red">Stream ([0-9]+)<\/font>
```

This line is responsible for getting humber of stream which is numerical and need to be at least 1 digit or more.

Comment: thanks alot , works fine,, but some are printing time wrongly..like
            [28] => 08 FF vs Valerenga IF 5.30pm-7.30pm , can u take the number only between am or pm..I will be really thankful to u :)

Comment: @ Robert Podwika ? did u modify it ..if so please leave a comment..thanks :)

Comment: but still some parts are showing like 
            [25] => 1919 vs SV Grodig 5.30 , please help be robert :)

Comment: it's easy to change you need add 0-9 also for first match of name I've edited again. If you follow what I've written you will find out how to do it yourself it's not really difficult if you have almoust whole regex.

Comment: @VishnuVishwa No offence, but "do this for me", "change that for me", "this doesn't work, halp". you come across like a [help vampire here](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). Stack Overflow is not a "gimme teh codez" site.

Comment: Thanks alot :) actually that was kinda emergency..thats why did not read it. ...now its completed..now i will read and study it :) thank you.

Comment: hey ,, finally where is tha am , pm...i tried to add {a,p,A,P,m,M} but that did not work

Comment: I don't understand [a,p,A,P,m,M]{2} this suits for am, pm if you want to include it to hours just see edited code it's about () where you put it. It's subpattern that it's given into array.

Comment: thanks alot.You are awesome..and your exmplantion of code it superb :)

Comment: hey..sometime i get            
            [65] => 1. Division Kristiansund BK vs Hï¿½dd 6.00pm
 ...thats the probelem ?

Comment: Add to [] this characters `ďż˝` you didn't mention it before

Comment: which bracket ? there are lots of barckets